# What C# using directive should be specified to connect to MS Access?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to open MS Access database from C# WinForms to run there a VBA code.

I've found a code snippet in Microsoft Support that seems to fit my request (see below) but got an error: "The type or namespace name 'Access' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

A reference Microsoft.Ofice.Interop.Access is already present in my project so I guess the problem is in missing a correct using directive.

Any help will be much appreciated...

```
Access.Application oAccess = null;

// Start a new instance of Access for Automation:
oAccess = new Access.ApplicationClass();

// Open a database in exclusive mode:
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(
"c:\\mydb.accdb", //filepath
true //Exclusive
);
```

Comment: Read about OLEDB. This is what you need.

Comment: Because in your code  you haven't specified the full qualified class name IE: _Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application_ Please re-read what is the purpose of the [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Comment: Thank you Steve, both for the answer and for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Microsoft Office Interop

```
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
```

Brows COM references for Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library.